# okHttp call works from app, but not when made in service - fails with ConnectException: Network is unreachable

Tags: android, okhttp

I am attempting to create an android service that will make REST calls using OkHttp.  The call sequence is as follows:

1. App calls startService(Intent) to start the service, passing relevant information in the Intent
2. The service extends the IntentService and handles one Intent at a time
3. The service attempts to call the web service, but it fails immediately with the `ConnectException - Network is unreachable`

If I change the code to skip the service and just have the app call the web service directly from a thread, the call succeeds.

More background:

1. The android device is connected to my laptop via adb (2 USB connectors with network cable)
2. My laptop is running Android Studio to debug the app/service
3. My laptop is also hosting the web services
4. The web service URL the android device is using is the IP of the adb connection to my laptop.  Hence, it looks something like this: http://10.10.10.101:8080/api/v1/doStuff
5. There is no Wifi or cellular connection on this device yet.  Only the adb connection.
6. The android device is able to ping my laptop using this IP address
7. targetSdkVersion 28
8. OkHttp version 4.3.1

The service is defined as follows in the manifest (notice how the service runs in a different process):

```
        <service
            android:name=".webapi.WebAPIService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:process=":webapi">
        </service>
```

The manifest includes the following permissions which the service should inherit, I believe:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_TIME"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SHUTDOWN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

I see two warnings that I believe are benign after doing some googling:

```
W/ContextImpl: Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user: android.app.ContextImpl.startService:1357
```

```
Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform$configureTrustManager$1>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/conscrypt/ConscryptHostnameVerifier;
```

Any ideas why the same OkHttp code would work when the app calls it, but not when the service calls it?

**UPDATE:**
If I have the service run in the same process as the app, then the web service call succeeds.  If the service runs in its own process (like I have it defined above), the call fails.  Is this a hint to anyone?

Comment: Why are you using a service?

Comment: If I place it in the app, the potentially long running operations (web service call) could be interrupted if the application is not in the foreground.

Comment: Just use WorkManager

Comment: I'm wondering if I should scrap the service and just use OkHttp directly from the app.  It looks like it has its own thread pools (https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/) .  I'm not seeing much advantage of using WorkManager either.  Is there any reason why this shouldn't be called from the app?

Comment: There are multiple reasons, one of them being configuration changes. What if the user rotates their device? Then you have to redo the network call... unless you use something like Rx/Coroutines. Then again, are you? Probably not. Also, there's no reason to use OkHttp directly when Retrofit exists.

Comment: @MarkBrown did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @dewijones92 I stopped trying to use the service and just made the calls from the application itself.

Comment: @dewijones92 We did the same thing and just made calls directly from the app.  It's working fine for us.